# How to Access API Subcomponents in CoinGecko

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, coingecko

This is a portion of the code returned by CoinGecko API.

```
{
  "id": "bitcoin",
  "symbol": "btc",
  "name": "Bitcoin",
  },
  "image": {
    "thumb": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
    "small": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/small/bitcoin.png?1547033579"
  },
  "market_data": {
    "current_price": {
      "aed": 26429.239288693556,
      "ars": 430563.0457102599,
      "aud": 10256.814195551682,
      "bch": 35.13945542496315,
      "bdt": 610699.0910671571,
      "bhd": 2712.9039956563156,
      "bmd": 7195.153895430029,
      "bnb": 524.566548150439,
      "brl": 28924.295609858014,
      "btc": 1
```

Using Reactjs, I am trying to access the Canadian price of Bitcoin under "market data" and "current_price". I can successfully access the "id" but I cannot access any of the content under "image" or "market_data". I am not sure if I am using the correct notation. This is the unsuccessful code.

```
<h1> {data.id} </h1>
<h1> {data.symbol} </h1>
<h1> {data.market_data.current_price.cad} </h1>
```

These are the 2 errors returned from the console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_price' of undefined

```
The above error occurred in the <StockCrypto> component:

    at StockCrypto (http://localhost:3000/react-CryptoMarket/static/js/main.chunk.js:1332:81)
    at div
    at CryptoStockPage
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/react-CryptoMarket/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:59298:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/react-CryptoMarket/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:59500:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/react-CryptoMarket/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:58933:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/react-CryptoMarket/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:58553:35)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Comment: The notation is indeed correct, though your error implies that `market_data` is not a valid key at the same level as `id`. Assuming your code is exactly the same as what is posted above, it *should* work - perhaps double-check you've not made a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the verification. For some reason, the request for the market price sometimes works and it sometimes does not. I either get the error or the price is displayed correctly on the screen.  Do you know what could be causing this inconsistency?